# Select available rooms in given date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a hotel booking system and I just got stuck when trying to make a query that retrieves all available room types in a given range.

I have two tables `Rooms` and `Reservations`. The `Rooms` table hold the rooms in the hotel. Their number (`id`) and their type (`type`).

Table `Reservations` holds the reservations made by the clients. The reservation number (`id`), the associated room number (`room_id`), and date range (`from` and `to`)

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT room_id as available_room_number, type

FROM roomstesting

LEFT JOIN reservations ON roomstesting.id = reservations.room_id
WHERE reservations.id 
  NOT IN (reservations.e_from <='"2014-03-07 19:00:00' 
           AND reservations.e_to >='2014-03-08 19:00:00')
```

I was trying to get all the available room types in the range from March 7 to March 8. I was expecting to get the `modern room` as result of the query. Because `modern room id 4` has no reservations made overlapping with the date range and all the other 3 rooms all have reservations made from March 6 to March 9. But I am not getting the result I want. Below is the structure of my database (simplified)

Rooms

```
| id | type         |
|||||||||||||||||||||
|  1 | master suite |
|  2 | master suite |
|  3 | modern room  |
|  4 | modern room  |
```

Reservations

```
| id | room_id | from                | to                  |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|  1 |    1    | 2014-03-05 08:00:00 | 2014-03-09 08:00:00 |
|  2 |    2    | 2014-03-05 08:00:00 | 2014-03-09 08:00:00 |
|  3 |    3    | 2014-03-05 08:00:00 | 2014-03-09 08:00:00 |
```

Expected result

```
| available_room_number | type       |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|          4            | modern room|
```

If anyone here can tell me how I should approach this that would be perfect. Looking forward to your replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT room_id FROM reservations WHERE '2014-03-07 19:00:00' < e_to AND '2014-03-08 19:00:00' > e_from)
```

Comment: YAY?! this works for all the reservations that start / end inside that range, but doesn't take in account the reservations that started and end outside the range. I have adjusted the inner select to this `SELECT room_id
FROM reservations
WHERE '2014-03-07 19:00:00' < e_to
AND '2014-03-08 19:00:00' > e_from` And it works. If you can edit your answer to this Ill gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just reverse the comparison signs

WHERE reservations.e_from >'2014-03-07 19:00:00' 
           AND reservations.e_to <'2014-03-08 19:00:00'

Answer (score 1):

Room 4 doesn't have a reservation, so it's not being picked up by the `JOIN`. Try something like this:

```
SELECT    room_id, type
FROM      roomstesting
WHERE     room_id NOT IN (
             SELECT    reservations.room_id
             FROM      reservations
             WHERE     (
                          reservations.e_from <= '2014-03-07 19:00:00' AND
                          reservations.e_to >= '2014-03-08 19:00:00'
                       ) OR (
                          reservations.e_from <= '2014-03-07 19:00:00' AND
                          reservations.e_to < '2014-03-08 19:00:00'
                       ) OR
                       (
                          reservations.e_from > '2014-03-07 19:00:00' AND
                          reservations.e_to >= '2014-03-08 19:00:00'
                       ) OR
                       (
                          reservations.e_from > '2014-03-07 19:00:00' AND
                          reservations.e_to < '2014-03-08 19:00:00'
                       )
                       )
```

Answer (score 0):

I always try using BETWEEN and it works

```
select * from roomstesting 
where room_id not in
(select room_id from roomstesting where date between begin_date and end_date)
```